# A hairy black or white problem

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix prefix was a clown,
>   My infix infix gets around,
>   My suffix suffix is long dead,
>   You don't want me on your head.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you:

> COMEDO

*My prefix prefix was a clown*

> Coco <s>Bobo</s> was a famous clown, (Thanks @hexomino)
>  From your double use of prefix I think the actual prefix is CO

*My infix infix gets around*

> Using my thinking from the previous clue, I think this is Meme,
>  as they are spread around a lot.
>  And therefore the infix would be ME

*My suffix suffix is long dead*

> The Dodo bird has been famously extinct for a while,
>  Making the suffix DO

*A hairy black or white problem*

> A comedo is a clogged hair follicle, which can cause white heads or black heads. (Thanks @SecretSquirrel) And you don't want them on your face.

Comment: I think the answer might be instead rot13(pbzrqb). Would feel bad writing a separate answer as you are so close.

Comment: I was looking for something along the same idea, but how does it match the title ?

Comment: if think rot13(vg pbhyq or n oynpx urnq be n juvgr urnq) as the answer is another word for a rot13(pybttrq cber)

Comment: @hexomino & SecretSquirrel thanks for the help figuring out the final stretch :)