# Mint, orange or pear

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, animals

> My prefix prefix comes from near the Med,
>   my infix infix is slightly weird,
>   my suffix suffix is brightly coloured,
>   I am something sweet which may be sprayed.

Comment: A Riley Riley riddle riddle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are ...

> ... **bergamot**.

My prefix prefix comes from near the Med

> The **[Berber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berbers)** are people from Northern Africa.

my infix infix is slightly weird

> In other words: **gaga**.

my suffix suffix is brightly coloured

> the **[motmot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motmot)** is a tropical American bird with colourful plumage.

I am something sweet which may be sprayed

> [Bergamot oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergamot_essential_oil) is an essence used in perfumes. It is made from the rind of bergamot oranges.

Mint, orange or pear

> [Bergamot mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eau_de_Cologne_mint) is another term for eau de Cologne mint, a cultivated species of mint. [Bergamot oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergamot_orange) are what bergamot oil is made from. The name bergamot comes from Turkish via Italian and means Prince's pear: The bergamot orange is a citrus fruit that is slightly pear-shaped.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say:

> Seafoam salad

My prefix prefix comes from near the Med,

> Mediterranean *Sea*

my infix infix is slightly weird,

> Its consistency is made of a strange mix of ingredients not usually found together.

my suffix suffix is brightly coloured,

> The salad is brightly colored.

I am something sweet which may be sprayed.

> Seafoam can spray and this salad is sweet.

Title:

> It is mint colored and has orange gelatin and pears.

Prefix Prefix, Infix Infix, Suffix Suffix

> A clue that the item itself is what's being described rather than the word.

Comment: generally, puzzles like these on this site step through the answer [line by line](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/89901/13475), explaining why it fits. It's hard to see why you think that this is the answer, and giving an explanation helps others to understand, and might even make them more willing to upvote

Comment: A sweet fit but the answer is clued like [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73512/a-hairy-black-or-white-problem) and [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73800/corsets-movie-sets-and-assets)